# Updating Values in Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to update a key value in a dictionary but can't seem to get it working. This takes values from a CSV file, hashes them, and creates a dictionary. The dictionary is then used to lookup and see if the main keys are in a JSON file. If they are it should update the dictionary to show whether the value was found or not.

```
import csv
import json
import hashlib
import xlwings as xw

# Set Excel file this is being called from to get the filename of the JSON file to check
wb = xw.Book('MyExcelFile.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets('Sheet1')
filename = r'C:\PycharmProjects\MyJSONFile.json'

# Set CSV file to read from
my_file = open('testdata.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(my_file)

# Declare the dictionary variable
my_dict = {}

# Read the value to hash from the file
for row in reader:
    #row[0] will be the value to hash - it's actually the column number
    original_value = row[0].removeprefix('Val:')
    hash_value = original_value

    # Hash the value
    i = 0
    while i < 5000:
        hash_value = hashlib.sha512(str(hash_value).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
        i += 1

    # Add the original value, status, and hashed value to the dictionary
    my_dict[hash_value] = {'Status': row[1], 'Original Value': original_value}

# Open the JSON file
with open(filename) as my_JSON:
    data = json.load(my_JSON)

# THIS IS THE BIT I NEED TO GET WORKING - IT SHOULD UPDATE THE 'Status' KEY IF IT FINDS THE VALUE IN THE JSON FILE
for key in my_dict:
    if key in data["skrotyPodatnikowCzynnych"]:
        print('Found it: ' + key)
        my_dict[hash_value]['Status'] = 'This has been found'
        print(my_dict[hash_value]['Status'])
    else:
        print('Not found: ' + key)
        my_dict[hash_value]['Status'] = 'This is missing'
        print(my_dict[hash_value]['Status'])

print(my_dict)
```

Everything works fine until trying to update the dictionary after the JSON lookup. The results show this below, but when I run the final "print(my_dict)" line of code it hasn't updated the dictionary as the 'Status' field is still set to it's original value of 'Not Checked'.  I need to update the 'Status' field to show whether the 'hash_value' was found so that I can then pass it back to Excel.

NOTE: I have abbreviated some of the values to protect the identity of the data.

```
Found it: 72cc2ecf0dc8dd7e7b56555f0ccacdde13b37
This has been found
Found it: a496101c748deca2128d6d9b82d35e1490ce6
This has been found
Found it: 21e80e863969b2fb230dadd6c301cabf3cdb1
This is missing

{'72cc2ecf0dc8dd7e7b56555f0ccacdde13b37': {'Status': 'Not Checked', 'Original Value': '2021060911330097'}, {'72cc2ecf0dc8dd7e7b56555f0ccacdde13b37': {'Status': 'Not Checked', 'Original Value': '202106091133009779'}, {'72cc2ecf0dc8dd7e7b56555f0ccacdde13b37': {'Status': 'Not Checked', 'Original Value': '20210609113300977978249'}}
```

Thank you.

Comment: In your `for key in my_dict:` loop you're not setting the `hash_value` so it reuses the last hash_value that's been used in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```py
# THIS IS THE BIT I NEED TO GET WORKING - IT SHOULD UPDATE THE 'Status' KEY IF IT FINDS THE VALUE IN THE JSON FILE
for key in my_dict:
    if key in data["skrotyPodatnikowCzynnych"]:
        print('Found it: ' + key)
        my_dict[key]['Status'] = 'This has been found' # modify hash_value to key
        print(my_dict[key]['Status'])
    else:
        print('Not found: ' + key)
        my_dict[key]['Status'] = 'This is missing' # modify hash_value to key
        print(my_dict[key]['Status'])

print(my_dict)
```